# How to get cerain count of rows near specific row using PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is my test data:

```
id | name
---------
1  | aaa
2  | bbb
3  | ccc
4  | ddd
5  | eee
6  | fff
7  | ggg
```

And I need to get constant count of rows (N) in my result (sorting is always by id), when rows next to `main` are selected depending on the position. For example, when N = 5:

- If `main` is the first one (where name = 'aaa') then I need rows with id from 1 to 5.
- If `main` is in center (where name = 'ddd') then I need rows with id from 2 to 6.
- If `main` is the last one (where name = 'ggg') then I need rows with id from 3 to 7.
- If `main` is somewhere else (for example, where name = 'bbb') then I need rows with id from 1 to 5.

The main idea - if it is possible to get equal count of rows on both sides (before and after `main`). If it is not possible to get the most balanced sides.

Could anyone say how to do it?

Comment: Is `id` indexed? I would assume numbers are not consecutive.

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice little problem. You can do:

```
with
p (name) as (select 'bbb'),
m as (select t.* from t cross join p where t.name = p.name),
b as (
  select t.* from t cross join p where t.name < p.name order by id desc limit 5
),
a as (
  select t.* from t cross join p where t.name > p.name order by id limit 5
),
c as (select (select count(*) from b) as b, (select count(*) from a) as a),
r as (
  select 
    case
      when a + b <= 4 then 4
      when a = b then 2
      when a < b then a
      else 4 - b
    end as a,
    case
      when a + b <= 4 then 4
      when a = b then 2
      when a < b then 4 - a
      else b
    end as b
  from c
)
(select * from b order by id desc limit (select b from r))
union all (select * from m)
union all (select * from a order by id limit (select a from r))
order by id
```

Result:

```
 id  name 
 --- ---- 
 1   aaa  
 3   bbb  
 4   ccc  
 6   ddd  
 7   eee
```

See running example (with modified data for testing) at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qnowx7Q6mgboCEmq7NdwQV/0).

You can change the parameter in the second line from `'bbb'` to any other value to see how the query adapts the result to return the "closest" 5 rows.

As a final note, the query was written to make good use of the index on (`id`), so it should be fast even if the table has millions of rows.